# Replace my for loop by higher order function for getting keywords in my search component?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My function works as I expect (I think) but I want to change my loops with higher order functions, but I'm struggling a bit..

Here is my code :

```js
const getKeywords = (str) => {
    var i, j, result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < str.length + 1; j++) {
            result.push(str.slice(i, j).toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getKeywords("testing my function"))
```

If someone has an idea of which Higher Order Functions to use to replace my nested loop thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
const getKeywords = (str) => {
  return [].concat.apply([], str.split("").map((currentValue, i, a) => {
    return a.filter((currentValue, j) => i <= j).map((currentValue, k, b) => { 
      return b.filter((currentValue, l) => l <= k ).join("").toLowerCase();
    });
  }))
}

console.log(getKeywords("testing my function"));
```

Process:

1. Use the [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to convert the string to an array of characters (`["t","e","s","t",` etc `]`)
2. Loop through each character in that array (index `i`). As you are going through the entire array and returning an element each time, use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
3. For each map index `i`, loop through and return an array of elements where index `j` is greater than or equal to `i` (duplicate the array, removing the first character each time). This is conditional and returns an array, so you use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
4. For each of those (`map()`, index `k`), return an array of elements up to that index (`filter`, index `l`, condition `l <= k`)
5. Join the results of that last filter to a string using [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and make that lowercase.
6. use [concat() and apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays) to flatten the results to a single array.